# Maven release plugin with classifer snapshot dependencies from command line

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-release-plugin

I'm attempting to run the maven release plugin from the command line in batch mode for a multi-module project that has dependences that are deployed to the maven repository with a classifier.

The release:prepare works correctly when it's not in batch-mode and prompts for all the unresolved snapshot dependences including the ones with a classifier and the release completes successfully.

When I look at the release.properties file I see ...

**Regular dependencies** identified like

```
project.rel.groupIdXYZ:artifactIdXYZ=2.0.3.4
project.dev.groupIdXYZ:artifactIdXYZ=2.0.3.4-SNAPSHOT
```

**Classifier dependencies** identified like

```
dependency.groupIdABC:artifactIdABC.release=2.0.3.4
dependency.groupIdABC:artifactIdABC.development=2.0.3.4-SNAPSHOT
```

with no actual classifier id.

Now I try it through the command line with a command line like ...

```
mvn --batch-mode -P release,nexus -Dtag=rm2.0.3.4 -Dproject.rel.groupIdXYZ:artifactIdXYZ=2.0.3.4 -Dproject.dev.groupIdXYZ:artifactIdXYZ=2.0.3.4-SNAPSHOT -Ddependency.groupIdABC:artifactIdABC.development=2.0.3.4-SNAPSHOT -Ddependency.groupIdABC:artifactIdABC.release=2.0.3.4 -DreleaseVersion=2.0.3.4 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0.3.4-SNAPSHOT -DdryRun=true release:prepare
```

and get

```
Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
groupIdABC:artifactIdABC:jar:classifierIdABC:2.0.3.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

I've verified that the classifier artifacts are in my local maven repo our corporate central  maven repo.  I've tried specifing the classifier artifacts as

```
-Dproject.rel.groupIdABC:artifactIdABC:jar:classifierIdABC=2.0.3.4
```

and still the same error.

Any pointers to being able to run this from the command line would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, I have no clue to this at the moment. But you could try to raise this as a bug/question on the Maven JIRA (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE for version 2 of the plugin) for the release plugin.

Comment: Why is there 2.0.3.3 in the error message, but 2.0.3.4 in all other snippets? You don't provide information on how to resolve 2.0.3.3 snapshot dependency.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you using version 2.0 of the maven-rlease-plugin or a more recent one?

Answer (score 0):

What if you set `allowTimestampedSnapshots` property to `true`? Does it still throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

maven-release-plugin requires all dependency versions to be non-SNAPSHOT ... for obvious reasons. Must be final release.

If you know your dependencies do have non-SNAPSHOT versions available, (you previously released them), then you could use versions-maven-plugin to automatically update the pom.xml

```
mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DallowSnapshots=false -Dincludes=com.my.*
```

And to prevent release-plugin from complaining about the uncommitted change to the pom.xml...

```
 mvn release:prepare ... -DcheckModificationExcludeList=pom.xml
```